# Closed Form for $~\int_0^1\frac{\text{arctanh }x}{\tan\left(\frac\pi2~x\right)}~dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

> Does $$~\displaystyle{\int}_0^1\frac{\text{arctanh }x}{\tan\left(\dfrac\pi2~x\right)}~dx~\simeq~0.4883854771179872995286585433480\ldots~$$ possess a closed form expression ?

---

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309701) recent post, in conjunction with my age-old interest in [Gudermannian functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function), have inspired me to ask this question. The reason I suspect that such a closed form might possibly exist is because the integration interval is “meaningful” for both functions used in the integrand. However, [none](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign) of the [various](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration) approaches that I can [think](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_expansion) of seem to be of any help. Perhaps I'm missing something ?

Comment: Oh, @Cleo, where art thou ?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here is an approach.

We give a preliminary result.

---

### A series of squares of logarithms

---

Let us consider the poly-Hurwitz zeta function initially defined by the series
$$
\begin{align}
  \displaystyle \zeta(s,t\mid a,b) := \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^{s}(n+b)^t}, 
  \quad \Re a>-1, \, \Re b>-1, \, \Re (s+t)>1. \tag1
\end{align} 
$$
The function $ \displaystyle \zeta(\cdot,\cdot \mid a,b)$ extends  to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}^2$  with only singularities on the set $\displaystyle \left\{(s,t) \in \mathbb{C}^2, \,\Re (s+t)=1\right\}$. It clearly generalizes the classic [Hurwitz zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function) initially defined by the series
$$
\begin{align}
  \displaystyle \zeta(s,a) := \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(n+a)^s}, 
  \quad \Re a>0, \, \Re s>1. \tag2
\end{align} 
$$

We have the following new result.

> **Theorem.** Let $a, b$ be complex numbers such that $\Re a>-1$ and $\Re b>-1$.
>
> Then
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\log^2\!\left(\! \frac{n+a}{n+b}\!\right)= \zeta’’(0,a+1)+ \zeta’’(0,b+1)-2\zeta^{1,1}(0,0\mid a,b)\tag3
> \end{align} 
> $$

where $\log (z)$ denotes the principal value of the logarithm defined for all $z \neq 0$ by
$$
\log (z) = \ln |z|+i \arg z, \quad -\pi<\arg z\leq \pi,
$$
$ \displaystyle \zeta(\cdot,a)$ and $ \displaystyle \zeta(\cdot,\cdot \mid a,b)$ denoting the Hurwitz zeta function and the poly-Hurwitz zeta function respectively and where $$ \zeta’’(0, a)=\partial_{s}^2\left.\zeta(s,a)\right|_{s=0},\qquad \zeta^{1,1}(0,0\mid a,b)=\partial_{st}^2\left.\zeta(s,t\mid a,b)\right|_{(s,t)=(0,0)}.$$

*Proof.* 
On the one hand, one has 
$$
\begin{align}
&\partial_a \left(\zeta''(0,a+1)+\zeta''(0,b+1)-2\zeta^{1,1}(0,0\mid a,b)\right)\\\\
&= \left.\partial_s^2 \left(\partial_a \zeta(s,a+1)\right)\right|_{s=0}-2\left.\partial_{st}^2 \left(\partial_a \zeta(s,t\mid a,b)\right)\right|_{(s,t)=(0,0)}\\\\
&= \left.\partial_s^2 \left(-s\zeta(s+1,a+1)\right)\right|_{s=0}-2\left.\partial_{st}^2 \left(-s\zeta(s+1,t\mid a,b)\right)\right|_{(s,t)=(0,0)}\\\\ 
&= -\left.\left(2\zeta'(s+1,a+1)+s\zeta''(s+1,a+1)\right)\right|_{s=0}+2\left.\partial_s \!\left(s\zeta^{0,1}(s+1,t\mid a,b)\right)\right|_{(s,t)=(0,0)}\\\\ 
&=2\gamma_1(a+1)-2\gamma_1(b,a),
\end{align}
$$  using **Theorem** $1$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569).

On the other hand, one has

$$
\begin{align}
\partial_a\! \left(\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\log^2\!\left(\! \frac{n+a}{n+b}\!\right)\right)
\!=  2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{\log (n+a)-\log (n+b)}{n+a}
=2\gamma_1(a+1)-2\gamma_1(b,a),
\end{align}
$$
using **Theorem** $2$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569).

Observing that 
$$
\zeta(s,t\mid 0,0)=\zeta(s+t), \quad \zeta(s,1)=\zeta(s),
$$ where $\zeta(\cdot)$ is the Riemann zeta function, then 
$$
\zeta’’(0,1)-\zeta^{1,1}(0,0\mid 0,0)=0
$$ and both sides of $(3)$ vanish at $a=b=0$.

Thus $(3)$ holds true. $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \Box$

---

### Lucian's integral

---

We prove that Lucian's integral is related to the preceding family of logarithmic series.

> **Proposition 1.** We have
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_0^1 \frac{\text{arctanh}\: x}{\tan \left( \frac{\pi}2x\right)}\:{\rm d}x=\frac\pi4-\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\log^2\!\left(\! \frac{2n-1 }{ 2n+1}\!\right).\tag{4}
> \end{align} 
> $$

*Proof.* Let us proceed on Jack D'Aurizio's route which starts by using the standard expansion 
$$
\frac1{\tan \left( \frac{\pi}2x\right)}=\frac{2}{\pi x}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n+2)}{2^{2n}}x^{2n+1},\quad 0<x<1,\tag{5}
$$ then integrating termwise using
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n+1}\:\text{arctanh} \:x \:{\rm d}x\\
&=\frac1{2(n+1)(2n+1)}+\frac{\ln2}{2(n+1)}+\frac1{4(n+1)}\left(\gamma+\psi \left(n+\frac12 \right) \right)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
to get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\text{arctanh}\: x}{\tan \left( \frac{\pi}2x\right)}\:{\rm d}x &=\frac{\pi }{4}+\frac{2}{\pi }(1-\ln 2)\ln\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\\\\&-\frac{1}{\pi }\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n+2)}{(2n+1)2^{2n}}-\frac{1}{\pi }\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n+2)\left(\psi\left(n+\frac12\right)+\gamma\right)}{(n+1)2^{2n+2}}. \tag7
\end{align} 
$$
We are left with two non trivial series to evaluate.

We prove that each series may be evaluated using the poly-Stieltjes constants.

One may write
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n+2)}{(2n+1)2^{2n}}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^{2n+2}}\frac1{(2n+1)2^{2n}}\\
&=4\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{(2n+1)}\frac1{(2k)^{2n+2}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1k\left(\log \left(1 + \frac1{2k}\right)-\log \left(1 - \frac1{2k}\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1k\left(\log \left(k + \frac12\right)-\log \left(k - \frac12\right)\right)\\
&=\gamma_1\Big({\small\frac12,0}\Big)-\gamma_1\Big({\small-\frac12,0}\Big) \tag{8}
\end{align}
$$ using Theorem $2$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364452/evaluate-int-0-frac-pi2-frac11x21-tan-x-mathrm-dx/1381569#1381569).

To evaluate the last series on the right hand side of $(7)$, one may check with some algebra that, for any complex number $z$ satisfying $|z|<1$, the following identity holds true:
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\psi\left(n+\frac12\right)+\gamma}{n+1}z^{2n+2}\\
&=2z\log\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z} \right)-2\left(1- \ln 2 \right)\log (1-z^2)+\frac12\log^2\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z} \right). \tag9
\end{align}
$$
Then
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\zeta(2n+2)\left(\psi\left(n+\frac12\right)+\gamma\right)}{(n+1)2^{2n+2}} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{k^{2n+2}}\frac{\psi\left(n+\frac12\right)+\gamma}{(n+1)2^{2n+2}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\psi\left(n+\frac12\right)+\gamma}{n+1}\frac1{(2k)^{2n+2}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1k \log \left(\frac{1-\frac1{2k}}{1+\frac1{2k}}\right)-2\left(1- \ln 2 \right)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log \left(1 - \frac1{4k^2}\right)+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log^2 \left(\frac{1-\frac1{2k}}{1+\frac1{2k}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1k \log \left(\frac{k-\frac12}{k+\frac12}\right)+2\left(1- \ln 2 \right)\ln\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log^2\!\left(\! \frac{2k-1 }{ 2k+1}\!\right)\\
&=\gamma_1\Big({\small-\frac12,0}\Big)-\gamma_1\Big({\small\frac12,0}\Big)+2\left(1- \ln 2 \right)\ln\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\frac12\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log^2\!\left(\! \frac{2k-1 }{ 2k+1}\!\right).\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
Inserting $(10)$ and $(8)$ into $(7)$ gives the announced result $(4)$. $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \Box$

We deduce the following closed form.

> **Proposition 2.** We have
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_0^1 \frac{\text{arctanh} x}{\tan \left( \frac{\pi}2x\right)}\:{\rm d}x=\frac\pi4+\frac2\pi\ln^2 2+\frac1\pi\ln 2\ln \pi+\frac1\pi\zeta^{1,1}\Big(0,0 \:\Bigr\rvert {\small-\frac12,\frac12}\Big). \tag{11}
> \end{align} 
> $$

*Proof.* One may observe that
$$
\begin{align}
\zeta\left(s,\frac12 \right) & = \left(2^s-1 \right)\zeta(s) \tag{12}\\
\zeta\left(s,\frac32 \right) & = \left(2^s-1 \right)\zeta(s)-2^s, \tag{13}
\end{align}
$$ and [recalling](http://dlmf.nist.gov/25.6#E11) that $\zeta'(0)=-\frac12 \ln (2 \pi)$, one may obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\zeta''\left(0,\frac12 \right) & = -\frac32 \ln^2 2 - \ln 2 \ln \pi \tag{14}\\
\zeta''\left(0,\frac32 \right) & = -\frac52 \ln^2 2 - \ln 2 \ln \pi. \tag{15}
\end{align}
$$
From $(4)$ and $(3)$, we have
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{\text{arctanh}\: x}{\tan \left( \frac{\pi}2x\right)}\:{\rm d}x
&=\frac\pi4-\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\log^2\!\left(\! \frac{2n-1 }{ 2n+1}\!\right)\\\\
&=\frac\pi4-\frac1{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\log^2\!\left(\! \frac{n-\frac12 }{ n+\frac12}\!\right)\\\\
&=\frac\pi4-\frac1{2\pi}\left( \zeta''\left(0,-\frac12+1 \right)+ \zeta''\left(0,\frac12+1 \right)-2\zeta^{1,1}\Big(0,0 \:\Bigr\rvert {\small-\frac12,\frac12}\Big)\right)\\\\
&=\frac\pi4-\frac1{2\pi}\left( \zeta''\left(0,\frac12 \right)+ \zeta''\left(0,\frac32 \right)-2\zeta^{1,1}\Big(0,0 \:\Bigr\rvert {\small-\frac12,\frac12}\Big)\right),
\end{align}
$$ by appealing to $(14)$ and $(15)$, we get $(11)$. $\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \Box$

By combining **Proposition** $2$ and pisco125's derivation we obtain the following new closed forms.

> **Proposition 3.** We have
>
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\infty} {\ln (1+x^2)\over {e^{2\pi x}+1}}\:{\rm d}x =&\:\frac\pi4+\frac1{2\pi}\ln^2 2+\frac1\pi\zeta^{1,1}\Big(0,0 \:\Bigr\rvert {\small-\frac12,\frac12}\Big) \tag{16}
> \\\\
>  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^k\over k} \text{Ci} (2k\pi)=&\:\frac{\pi^2}4+\frac12\ln^2 2+\:\zeta^{1,1}\Big(0,0 \:\Bigr\rvert {\small-\frac12,\frac12}\Big) \tag{17}
> \end{align} 
> $$

where $\text{Ci} (\cdot)$ is the [cosine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral) and where  $\displaystyle \zeta(\cdot,\cdot\mid a,b)$ is the poly-Hurwitz zeta function.

Answer (score 33):

This is a partial answer, but it reduces the problem into handling a more decent integral.

### $$\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{1} \text{arctanh } x \cot\left({\pi x\over 2}\right)dx = {3\ln^2 2 \over 2\pi}+{\ln \pi \ln 2\over \pi}+ {\int_{0}^{\infty} {\ln(1+x^2)\over e^{2\pi x}+1}dx}}$$

Note that the analogous integral is known $$\int_{0}^{\infty} {x\ln(1+x^2)\over e^{2\pi x}+1}dx = {19\over 24}-{23\over 24} \ln 2-{1\over 2}\ln A$$
where $A$ is the [Glaisher–Kinkelin constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant).

However, it seems that the fundamental nature of the one related to the question is entirely different, hence its value must be derived in some other manners not known to me.

I briefly outlined the process of obtaining the blue equality below.

---

### Identities/facts that will be used:

- $$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(2kx) = {1\over 2}\cot x - {\cos(2n+1)x\over {2\sin x}} $$ this is true whenever $\sin x$ isn't zero.
- [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma), which more or less states that:
  $$\text{For an absolutely integrable function $f(x)$ on the interval $[a,b]$, then}\\ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\cos (nx) dx = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{a}^{b} f(x)\sin (nx) dx = 0 $$
- $$\text{Ci} (x) = -\int_{x}^{\infty} {\cos x\over x} dx, \text{Si} (x) = \int_{0}^{x} {\sin x\over x}dx$$ they are the [cosine and sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Cosine_integral)
- Using some elemtary (but delicate) techniques, one can have, for any $a>0$, $$\int_{0}^{\infty} {1\over x}\left({1\over{1+ax}}-\cos ax\right)dx = \gamma$$
  And also this series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} {\ln k \over k} = \gamma \ln 2 - {{\ln^2 2}\over 2} $$
- $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\sin ax dx={a\over {a^2+1}}$$

---

### Proof

The original integral is equal to $$ {2\over \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \text{arctanh} {2x\over \pi}\cot x dx = {2\over \pi} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  {{\ln(1+{2x\over \pi})-\ln(1-{2x\over \pi})}\over 2} \cot x dx$$

And by the first fact, $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  {\ln\left(1\pm{2x\over \pi}\right)} \cot x dx = 2\sum_{k=1}^n \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \ln\left(1\pm{2x\over \pi}\right)\sin(2kx) dx + \\ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}       {\cos(2n+1)x\over \sin x}\ln\left(1\pm{2x\over \pi}\right) dx$$
Note that the function $\ln\left(1\pm{2x\over \pi}\right)\over \sin x$ is absolutely integrable its integrated range, thus as $n$ approaches infinity, the latter integral tends to zero. 
Thus $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  {\ln\left(1\pm{2x\over \pi}\right)} \cot x dx = 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi\over 2} \ln\left(1\pm{2x\over \pi}\right)\sin(2kx) dx
 $$

---

For the first one, it's striaghtforward
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  {\ln\left(1+{2x\over \pi}\right)} \sin(2kx) dx & = \ln 2 {(-1)^{k+1}\over {2k}} + {1\over{k\pi}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  {\cos{2kx}\over {1 +{2x\over\pi} }} dx \\
& = \ln 2 {(-1)^{k+1}\over {2k}} + {(-1)^{n}\over{2k}} \int_{1}^{2}  {\cos{k\pi x}\over x} dx \\
& = \ln 2 {(-1)^{k+1}\over {2k}} + {(-1)^{n}\over{2k}} [\text{Ci} (2k\pi) - \text{Ci} (k\pi)]
\end{align}$$
Where we have used integration by parts in the first line, a simple substitution in the second and the definition of cosine integral in the third. Hence
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2} \ln\left(1+{2x\over \pi}\right)\cot x dx & = \ln^2 2 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^k\over k} [\text{Ci} (2k\pi) - \text{Ci} (k\pi)]
\end{align}$$

---

For the second one, it might require some gist, 
$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}  {\ln\left(1-{2x\over \pi}\right)} \sin(2kx) dx & = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} {\ln\left[1-{2\over \pi}\left({\pi\over 2} -x\right)\right]} \sin\left[2k\left({\pi\over 2} -x\right)\right] dx \\
& = (-1)^{k+1} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  {\ln\left({2x\over \pi}\right)} \sin(2kx) dx \\
& = {(-1)^{k+1}\over {2k}} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}  {\ln\left({2x\over \pi}\right)}  d(1-\cos 2kx) \\
& = {(-1)^{k}\over {2k}} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} {{1-\cos 2kx} \over x}  dx \\
& = {(-1)^{k}\over {2k}} \left\{ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} {1\over x}\left(1-{1\over {1+2kx}}\right)  dx+ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} {1\over x}\left({1\over {1+2kx}}-\cos 2kx\right)  dx \right\} \\
& = {(-1)^{k}\over {2k}} \left\{ \ln(1+k\pi) + \gamma - \int_{\pi/2}^{\infty} {1\over x}\left({1\over {1+2kx}}-\cos 2kx\right)  dx \right\} \\
& = {(-1)^{k}\over {2k}} \{ \ln k +\ln \pi + \gamma -\text{Ci} (k\pi) \}
\end{align}$$
Using the series given above, one can get
$$\int_{0}^{\pi\over 2} \ln\left(1-{2x\over \pi}\right)\cot x dx = -{{\ln^2 2}\over 2} - \ln \pi \ln 2 - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^k\over k} \text{Ci} (k\pi)$$

---

Hence, putting them altogether, $$\int_{0}^{1} \text{arctanh } x \cot\left({\pi x\over 2}\right)dx = {3\ln^2 2 \over 2\pi}+{\ln \pi \ln 2\over \pi} +{1\over \pi} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^k\over k} \text{Ci} (2k\pi)$$
The latter series is particularly intractable, and by converting $x\over{x^2+1}$ with means a integral (see the last fact), it can be shown that $$\text{Ci} {(2k\pi)} = -\int_{0}^{\infty} {x\over{x^2+1}}e^{-2n\pi x}dx  $$ 
$$ \text{Hence,} \space\space\space\space\space\space  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {(-1)^k\over k} \text{Ci} (2k\pi) = \int_{0}^{\infty} {x\over{x^2+1}}\ln (1+e^{-2\pi x})dx = \pi \int_{0}^{\infty} {\ln (1+x^2)\over {e^{2\pi x}+1}}dx $$

Comment: Perhaps by expanding $\ln(1+t)$ and/or $\dfrac1{u+1}$ into an infinite series, and reversing the order of summation and integration ?

Comment: @Lucian I tried it for several hours, but it seems a dead end. There are a lot of similar-looking integrals with closed-form known, but still, I am unable to handle this one.

Comment: You're right, various series expansions do indeed seem fruitless, as do some substitutions. I also thought about using differentiation under the integral sign, but it also led nowhere.

Comment: By contour integration one can show that

$$\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{e^{2\pi x}+1}\ dx=\int^\frac{1}{2}_0\ln\left(\frac{\Gamma(2-x)}{\Gamma(1+x)}\right)\tan(\pi x)\ dx$$

Comment: @M.N.C.E.: I just arrived at a very similar result by replacing $H_{n-\tfrac12}$ in Jack's relation $(5)$ by its [integral expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).

Answer (score 10):

There are some simple manipulations that can be carried on. For starters,

$$\cot x=\frac{1}{x}-2\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\zeta(2n+2)}{\pi^{2n+2}}x^{2n+1}\tag{1}$$

hence

$$\cot\frac{\pi x}{2}=\frac{2}{\pi x}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\zeta(2n+2)}{4^n}x^{2n+1}\tag{2}$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{1}\text{arctanh}(x)\cdot x^{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2(n+1)}\bigg(\ln2+\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2}H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}\bigg)\tag{3}$$

so

$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\text{arctanh}(x)\cdot\cot\frac{\pi x}{2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{2}{\pi}(1-\ln2)\ln\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{S}{2\pi}\tag{4}$$

where

$$S=\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{\zeta(2n+2)}{4^n}\bigg(\frac{2}{2n+1}+\frac{H_{n-\frac{1}{2}}}{2(n+1)}\bigg)\tag{5}$$

but I am not so sure the last series can be further simplified. In any case, $(4)$ looks like a good starting point.

Comment: "...(4) looks like a good starting point..." No, it absolutely doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps by employing the [integral expression for harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation), and expanding the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) into its own series, then switching the order of the various summations and integrations ?

Comment: Why not use $\mathrm{arctanh}(x)=\sum_k\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}$ ?

Comment: @Tom-Tom: that is used, too. To compute $\int_{0}^{1}x^{m}\text{arctanh}(x)\,dx$, for instance.

Comment: @Tom-Tom: I get $~\displaystyle\int_0^1x^k~\cot\bigg(\frac\pi2~x\bigg)~dx ~=~ \frac{\ln4}\pi ~+~ \sum_{n=1}^{[k/2]}(-1)^n~{\large a}_{~2n+1,~k}~\frac{\zeta(2n+1)}{\pi^{2n+1}},~$ where ${\large a}_{3,~k}=\dfrac32~k~(k-1),~$ but I can't make any sense of the rest of $~{\large a}_{~2n+1,~k}$ for $n>1.$

Comment: @L.G.: Any alternative suggestions ? :-$)$

Comment: Why the downvote?