# How to Calculate this series with $\ln$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Calculate that$$I=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\ln k}{(k+2)^{3/2}}$$

In fact I haven't dealt with this kind of problem.And, this series converges so slowly that Wolfram alpha do a wrong answer in low digit.

One possible thing I can do is prove that$$I<2+\sqrt{2}.$$But it seems useless.

Comment: Interesting, 
Mathematica `N[Sum[Log[k]/(k+2)^(3/2),{k,2,Infinity}],80]`
gives $3.2269874138382259858799993951213658615526991749281667556412273599844657103288563$, 
while 
`(PARI/GP) sumpos(k=2,log(k)/(k+2)^(3/2))` gives 
$3.2269874138382259858799993949523024137887834415745074284112130236326655149552720$.
They disagree starting from 27th figure.

Comment: @g.kos They are probably using different numerical techniques. Perhaps one is using series acceleration, whereas the other is using Euler-Maclaurin, etc.

Comment: If the denominator were simply $k$ instead of $k+2$ the result could be stated in terms of the derivative of the zeta function. As it stands there is no acceptable closed form.

Comment: The phrasing seems odd.  Does the problem this came from have more information?

Comment: @K.defaoite I hardly forget this situation. Maybe it really doesn't have a closed form.

Comment: @g.kov. Could you try to look at my last sentence ? I do not understand why I have problems  "close" to $a=2$. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

This problem looks very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123446/how-to-evaluate-sum-k-3-infty-frac-ln-kk2-4/4127632?noredirect=1#comment8538513_4127632).

Consider the more general case

$$I(a)=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log( k)}{(k+a)^{3/2}}$$ and use a series expansion around $a=0$
$$\frac{\ln k}{(k+a)^{3/2}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{3}{2}}{n}\, k^{-n-\frac{3}{2}}\log (k)\,\, a^n$$
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty \binom{-\frac{3}{2}}{n}\, k^{-n-\frac{3}{2}}\log (k)=\frac{2 \sqrt{\pi }}{\Gamma
   \left(-n-\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma (n+1)} \,\zeta '\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)$$ making $a=2$  does not gives the correct answer.

For $\color{red}{a=1}$, this works like a charm with a fast convergence. Computing the partial sums (from $n=0$ to $n=p$), we have numerically
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \sum_{n=0}^p \\
 5 & 3.490688272 \\
 10 & 3.499057047 \\
 15 & 3.498737820 \\
 20 & 3.498749643 \\
 25 & 3.498749222 \\
 30 & 3.498749236
\end{array}
\right)$$

Same behaviour for any $a =\frac 3 2$ for a correct result.

Could the problem be related to the fact that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{(2 n+3)\,\, \zeta '\left(n+\frac{5}{2}\right)}{(2n+2)
  \,\, \zeta '\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}=0.5000002500 \quad > \quad \frac 12$$

Comment: It looks that the limit is exactly $\tfrac12$.